# How to remove certain images from some HTML code with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, image, search

I simply want to extract a certain image from a block of html text that may contain 5 different images--in the image I want, the url always starts with "http://yourhosthere.images.....," where the other images don't have that same beginning url structure. I just cannot figure out how to just grab that one image and ignore all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample of the HTML would help, but you can use `preg_match` like this:

```
<?

$html='<img src="http://yourhosthere.images/theimage.jpg">
<img src="http://thewrongimage.com/image.jpg">
';

$regex='/<img src="(http:\/\/yourhosthere\.images.*)">/';

preg_match ($regex,$html,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

tested: http://www.ideone.com/XbFcS

Answer (score 0):

You may want take a look at this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm - specifically at the attribute filters.